# Votar negativamente na pergunta sem comentar

Tags: debate, comportamento, voto-contra

Quando um usuário vota em uma pergunta como negativa ele não deveria ser obrigado a fazer um comentário? Na minha opinião é ruim você ter uma pergunta votada negativamente e não saber o porque do voto. Da atual forma só pede que seja considerado fazer um comentário, não seria melhor fazer um comentário?

Comment: Se é um novato, eu comento. Se é um veterano, espero que ele venha ao Meta pedir explicações ;) Mas, falando sério, tem algum caso específico que motivou perguntar isso? Ou pode citar exemplos onde acha que faltou um comentário? . . . Quanto à obrigatoriedade, pode desistir, não vai acontecer. E quanto às alternativas, acho que a possível duplicata responde a uma dúvida genérica como apresentada aqui.

Comment: Também já questionei isso. Hoje encaro como *livre arbítrio* do usuário. Vota quem quer, e justifica quem tem interesse em ajudar.

Comment: Há algum tempo ja tinha visto alguns novatos terem perguntas negativadas e nenhum comentário, mas se é duplicata podem fechar minha pergunta. Não tinha achado outra igual.

Comment: Não é dup daquela, @brasofilo. Talvez de outra, mas não daquela.

Comment: Sempre que você encontrar uma situação dessa e puder orientar ao recém chegado no site em qual a falha da pergunta e como resolver, legal.